# AngularJs Bootstrap UI Simple injector error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min but the code below is giving an error something like this. What is the problem?

"Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20InterfacePageController"

```
   function InterfacePageController(HttpService, crypto, $routeParams, $uibModal, $log) {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `ui.bootstrap` included in your main module like:

```
app.module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap")
```

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I got it :D Thank you :D